# Keep data at Fragment's Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Tab with two Fragments. Both Fragments download data from the network and display them.

The typical use case is : user opens app, Fragment_A downloads and displays data. If user clicks the other tab (Tab B) then Fragment_B downloads and displays data. 
If user goes back to Fragment_A data are already there and displayed but if he chooses once again to go to the next tab (Fragment_B) then it has to download again data.

So how I can keep data to Fragment_B while user navigates to the previous Tab (Tab A) ? Is this something that I can do with `onSaveInstanceState()` ?

Also, why does Fragment_A keeps data and not Fragment_B  ?  The code is identical the only thing that changes are the data being displayed.

Comment: You can download data in your Activity & connect that Activity with your Fragments to get the data

Comment: By download you mean to save it in my Activity ?

Comment: yes I am saying that save data in Activity & by data I mean is to save the response coming from server

Comment: if you are using ViewPager then add  `ViewPagerObject.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);`

Comment: @Mes  you have to keep if you want to use it like database or in shared preference.

Comment: @TUSHAR thanks a lot. But that doesnt explains why I don't have to keep the data of the first fragment ( unless cause it's first it's harder to kill so somehow it survives and keeps the data... )

Comment: Fragments have its own Life Cycle thats the Reason.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store your data in onSavedInstanceState() but it is not advised to use because Activity has its own life cycle methods and onSaveInstanceState() is not a part of it.

So its not guranteed to be called always.

For storing there are other options like

- SharedPreferences
- Sqlite Database